# Python: How to make an mp3 clip play using pyglet

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a GUI that displays a picture of a piano and when the user presses certain buttons it plays notes of a piano.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from pydub import AudioSegment
import winsound, sys
import pyglet


//creates a window with a picture of a piano on it
root = Tk()
photo = PhotoImage(file = "piano.png")
label = Label(root, image = photo)
label.pack()
//when the left arrow key is pressed I want it to play audio of a c note on    a piano
def leftkey(event):
    print("pressed")
    cnote = pyglet.resource.media("C:\\Users\\Ben\\Downloads\\cnote.mp3")
    cnote.play()
    pyglet.app.run()





root.bind('<Left>', leftkey)
root.focus_set()
root.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation this is what it says:

```
cnote = pyglet.media.load('cnote.mp3', streaming=False)
cnote.play()
```

Source:
http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/simple_audio_playback.html